# Import error from different directory in python (Err - No module named app)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, pytest, importerror

I have gone through numerous answers and tried most of them as well but still facing the same issue

My structure

```
 -- backend
    -- app
       -- __init__.py
       -- utils.py
       -- models.py
    -- pytest
       -- test_utils.py`
```

Now I want to import utils into the test_utils to be able to call the function and test it. My **init**.py is not empty and my test_utils.py looks like this

```
import sys, os.path
sys.path.insert(0 ,(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')) + '/app/'))
from utils import test_function

def test_test_function():
  a = test_function(5)
  assert a == 5
```

I checked my sys path is also pointing to correct directory but keep getting this error and I am using Python 2.7 in Linux

```
ImportError while importing test module '/home/richie/Documents/Project/backend/pytest/test_utils.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
../virenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py:709: in exec_
    exec("""exec _code_ in _globs_, _locs_""") 
test_utils.py:3: in <module>
    from utils import test_function
../app/utils.py:15: in <module>
    from models import Users, Accounts
../app/models.py:2: in <module>
    from app import db
E   ImportError: No module named app
```

Comment: Your code says `from utils import test_function`, but the error say that you imported `app`. This is not the code which produced that error.

Comment: @zvone I have added the complete error report, hope this helps but rest assured this is the code that runs as I have only 1 test file with 1 test case

Comment: Try renaming your `pytest` folder to another name? It may be conflicting with the actual pytest module.

Comment: Is backend on your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: @bunbun Nope that's not the problem, tried that as well.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I can see this in PYTHONPATH so maybe it is added:
'/home/richie/Documents/Project/backend/virenv/lib/python2.7'

Comment: That's not right. The actual backend folder has to be listed for the subfolders to be picked up as modules.

Comment: @MadPhysicist that is why I am using this:
sys.path.insert(0 ,(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')) + '/app/'))

But with your comment, I had to check something and it turns out that we have to individually add the path of all the packages we want to include and it is working now. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you figured that out. Without more concrete info, this isn't likely to help future readers much, so feel free to delete the question.

Comment: The error is in `from app import db`, which should be simply `import db`, assuming that you have "db.py" in "app" directory, although you did not mention it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a pytest.ini file in pytest/ folder.
The content of pytest.ini would be:--

[pytest]

python_paths = . ../app

Answer (score -2):

Turns out that have to add path to both app and utils and then it works

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
sys.path.append((os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')) + '/app/'))
```

Comment: That is a bad idea. You should either put "app" directory on the path and `import models`, or you should put the directory above "app" to path and then `import app.models`. Doing both duplicates all modules and class. Things get imported twice and bugs which are not easy to find occur with time. Don't do that.